# find the longest word using javascript / html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I tried to run the code but nothing is showing on my page.
i'm not sure where the mistakes are. I tried  typing javaScript code to find the longest word in a html form/input,then showing the output on the html body.

```js
function fnLongestWord(string){

 var words = str.split(" ");

 console.log(words);

 var findlongest=document.forms["Longestword"],

 var longest = "";


 for(let i=0; i < findlongest.length; i++){

  console.log(findlongest[i]);
 }

  if ( longest.length > findlongest.length) findlongest = longest;



 }
 console.log(longest);

 document.getElementById("showResult1") = "Number of vowels: "+ longest;
```

```html
<div id="LongWord" class="Tab">
 
 <form id="Longestword">
  
  <label>Enter text: <input  name="text "></label>
  <button type="button" onclick="fnLongestWord()"> Find longest word</button>

 </form>

  <!--here the output show-->

  <p id="showResult1"></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors
 ;Here you are calling `fnLongestWord` but not passing any argument while `fnLongestWord` expects a value

`var words = str.split(" ");` `str` is no where defined inside the function

You need to put this line `document.getElementById("showResult1") = "Number of vowels: "+ longest;` inside the function and this is an invalid assingment. You need to use `innerHTML` and assign the value to it

```js
function fnLongestWord(string) {
  var str = document.getElementById('input').value || string
  var words = str.split(" ");
  var longest = words.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.length - a.length;
  })
  document.getElementById("showResult1").innerHTML = "Number of vowels: " + longest[0];
}
```

```html
<div id="LongWord" class="Tab">

  <form id="Longestword">

    <label>Enter text: <input id = 'input' name="text "></label>
    <button type="button" onclick="fnLongestWord()"> Find longest word</button>

  </form>

  <!--here the output show-->

  <p id="showResult1"></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few mistakes in your code that need fixing.

Firstly, you call `fnLongestWord()` when you click the button, thus you are not passing in the string from the form. You need to get the string from the form by using:

`var str = document.getElementById('longestWord').value;`

This will get the `value` (the text) of the element with the `id` `longestWord`. This will get the text from the textbox (as I've given it the `id="longestWord"`)

Now you want to loop over your array of `words`. You can use `words.length` in the for loop to do this.

Next, you want to fix your `if` statement. Currently your syntax and logic are incorrect. Instead, you need to make it `if(longest.length < words[i].length) longest = words[i];` which reads that if the longest word currently found is smaller than our current word, set the new longest word equal to the current word (`word[i]`).

Lastly, you're not adding the answer to the page correctly. Instead, you should do:

`document.getElementById("showResult1").textContent += "Longest word is: " + longest;`

To set the longest word into the `showResult1` paragraph.

See working example below:

```js
function fnLongestWord() {
  var str = document.getElementById('longestWord').value;
  var words = str.split(" ");
  var longest = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (longest.length < words[i].length) longest = words[i];
  }
  document.getElementById("showResult1").textContent += "Longest word is: " + longest;
}
```

```html
<div id="LongWord" class="Tab">

  <form id="Longestword">

    <label>Enter text: <input id="longestWord" name="text "></label>
    <button type="button" onclick="fnLongestWord()"> Find longest word</button>

  </form>

  <!--here the output show-->

  <p id="showResult1"></p>

</div>
```